# crypt() returning *0 when passing in salt as variable

Tags: php

I am currently trying to code a login/registration system for a school project.

The password upon registration is encrypted using crypt() and a randomly generated salt and stored in the database.

When logging in, the salt and hash are retrieved from the database together and split using the explode function (I have stored them in salt.hash format, so using . to delimit).

I am then trying to use the user input password along with the salt retrieved from the database to generate a hash and compare it to the original taken from the database. This is where my problem lies.

```
   function fetch_hash($username, $dbc)
{
    $fetch_hash = $dbc->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username");
    $fetch_hash->bindValue(":username", $username);

    $fetch_hash->execute();

    $result = $fetch_hash->fetchAll();

    $hash = $result[0][password];
    return $hash; 
}

$correct_hash = fetch_hash($username, $dbc);
list($salt, $hash) = explode('.', $correct_hash); 

$password = "password"; 

echo "Generated hash : " . crypt($password, $salt); // Returns *0 
echo "Generated hash 2: " . crypt($password, "$2y$12$p7MTIQRBzetIWkH5zeqr5");  // Returns the correct hash which matches the on stored in the database
```

When passing in $salt as a parameter for crypt(), it returns *0 despite having the value of "$2y$12$p7MTIQRBzetIWkH5zeqr5" and when I enter it directly, it will return the correct hash to match the one stored in the database (i.e the login is correct). I really don't understand why it would not work as they are the exact same value.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Misread first time, output is the same here, https://eval.in/504198.

Comment: @chris85 Sorry, I update the original post with all of the original code, i'm guessing my problem lies in a different place than I thought? Thanks for the response

Comment: Don't use `crypt()`, use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `crypt()` you don't have to store hash and salt separately or delimit it in any way. `crypt` is totally able to work with its output:

```
// in register/password update/etc
$hash = crypt($password, $randomSalt);
// store to database



// in login routine
// retrieve hash as it was stored, no additional processing
if ($hash == crypt($password, $hash)) {
    // password matches, proceed with user authentication, sessions etc.
} else {
    // password mismatch
}
```

However, there's a relatively new API specifically intended to work with passwords: [password_* functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.password.php). It's more intuitive to use and has additional security measures crypt() does not (like resistance to time-based attacks). If your php installation is old (older than 5.5), you can use this [PHP polyfill](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) and still use the same API.

Comment: I did not know that! Thanks very much, got it working now - I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$correct_hash = '$2y$12$p7MTIQRBzetIWkH5zeqr5.$2mV0NZp92R3g';
list($salt, $hash) = explode('.', $correct_hash); 

$password = 'password'; 

echo "Generated hash : " . crypt($password, $salt . '$'); // Returns *0 
echo "Generated hash 2: " . crypt($password, '$2y$12$p7MTIQRBzetIWkH5zeqr5' . '$');
```

Comment: Using:

echo "Generated hash : " . crypt($password, $salt . '$'); // Returns *0 

Actually returns something now (does not return *0), however it does not match the original :( Thank you for the response :)